# Override onClick color / drawable

Tags: android, button, coding-style

I'm trying to find out, how to override standard onClick color (yellow) for [Button](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/Button.java;h=5e692d4fbbe1598ea07f78b736446285564283dc;hb=HEAD) with orange color?! (***during writing this question I've seen, that these are no colors, but images***)

Is there the easy way to do that? Or should I write a new style in that case?

I found in GIT, how com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle looks like. And I would like just copy and modify that button style a bit. But if I do it on that way, I get XML-Errors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector>
    <item 
        android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal"/>
    <item 
        android:state_window_focused="false" 
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
    <!-- Modified item -->
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" />
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
</selector>
```

Ok, I guess, I must fill selector's attribute  xmlns:android. If I fill it with "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", I get other errors. This time, because the android's drawable resources cann't be found.

Any suggestions?!

Thank you,

Mur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One working example. This xml is set as background drawable. Adjust the colors as you like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

    <item android:state_pressed="true" > 
        <shape> 
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="#FFAAAAAA"
                android:endColor="#FFAAAAAA"
                android:angle = "180" />
            <corners 
                android:radius="10dip" /> 
        </shape> 
    </item> 

    <item android:state_focused="true" > 
        <shape> 
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="#FF888888"
                android:endColor = "#FF888888"
                android:angle = "180"/> 
            <corners 
                android:radius="10dip" /> 
        </shape> 
    </item> 

    <item>         
        <shape>
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:endColor = "#FFFFFFFF"
                android:angle = "180" />
            <corners 
                android:radius="10dip" />
         </shape> 
    </item> 
</selector>
```

Additionally, you can define Stroke (button border).

Answer (score 1):

Mur, did you copy these resources (e.g. `btn_default_normal`) into your drawables folder? You'll have to get these resources (they can be found in your sdk folder under platforms/android-8/data/res/ then the different drawable folders) and then modify them to be the style that you need for each selector state.

Comment: No, I didn't ... I thought, there is a way to get access to them. I mean, you can get access to some system layouts.

Comment: You can usually get access to the parent layouts but nut their parts. So for example, you can access the current system's implementation of background state for a listview handler but not each of the pieces that make it up. If you wish to use those they are accessible in the SDK and you can simply copy them to your project.

Comment: there are too many different images for different sizes to copy (http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/res/res/drawable-hdpi;h=6e54b40a4b136aaa68016fd6ea1da16d9a9f8724;hb=HEAD)

Comment: You don't necessarily have to copy them all. Just copy the ones you need (e.g. drawable-hdpi, mdpi).

Comment: I also thought about it, but then I just took the solution of Desiderion. Unfortunately, I can not mark two solutions as correct